# I have variables and values in __init__ method and I want to make a new dict in another method where the variable as key and values of it as value

Tags: python, class, dictionary, methods, instance-variables

I have this--

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 1
        self.c = 2
        self.d = 4
```

I want --

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 1
        self.c = 2
        self.d = 4

    def do_nothing(self):
        a={'b':1,'c':2,'d':4}
```

how to use instance variable as key value in another r method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magic methods `__dict__` can help you

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

    def test(self):
        print(self.__dict__)

a = A()
a.test()
```

**Output**

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```